# Mismatch Range error on using IFs in sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I am using the formula below and getting an error "IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 2, column count: 2."
The code is to ignore Sat/Sun and pick High values of Thurs/Fri in case of Sat/Sun.

$c$1 is the present date.

Can someone help me debug this

`=ifs(weekday($C$1-1,2)=6,GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",today()-(today()-$C$1+4)),weekday($C$1-1,2)=7,GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",today()-(today()-$C$1+4)))`

Comment: May be your `GOOGLEFINANCE()` function returning 2 rows. Share a sample worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

`IFS` syntax is:

`IFS(condition1,value1,condition2,value2,...)`

It's important to realize all arguments should be of the same size. Same rows and columns. If  there's a mismatch, this error is thrown

> Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 2, column count: 2.

What this says is, 1x1 array is expected, but instead the function got 2x2 array and it doesn't know what to do with that.

In this specific case, `GOOGLEFINANCE` returns a 2x2 array with it's headers, while `WEEKDAY` returns a 1x1 array.

#### Solution:

Either increase the 1x1 array to 2x2 array or reduce  the 2x2 array to 1x1 array. Increasing can be done with array operations like `ARRAYFORMULA(IF())` or `IF(SEQUENCE())`. Decreasing can be done with `INDEX`/`QUERY` or `FILTER`

#### Snippet:

`=ifs(weekday($C$1-1,2)=6,INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",today()-(today()-$C$1+4)),2,2),weekday($C$1-1,2)=7,INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",today()-(today()-$C$1+4)),2,2))`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(WEEKDAY($C$1-1,2)=6, 
 GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",TODAY()-(TODAY()-$C$1+4)),
       IF(WEEKDAY($C$1-1,2)=7, 
 GOOGLEFINANCE($S$1,"high",TODAY()-(TODAY()-$C$1+4)), )), 2, 2)
```

reason why your IFS wont work: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471