# Use IFS() to return a range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm writing a Google Sheets named function, `GETTABLEOFCELL()`, that takes in a cell reference, and returns the Named Range that cell exists in.

Since I could not find a native function to determine if a cell is within the specified range, I've defined a helper function called `ISCELLINRANGE(range, cell)`.  I've confirmed that this helper function works for cells and ranges within the same sheet--good enough for my case.

```
ISCELLINRANGE(range, cell)
=AND(
  ROW(cell) >= ROW(range),
  ROW(cell) < ROW(range) + ROWS(range),
  COLUMN(cell) >= COLUMN(range),
  COLUMN(cell) < COLUMN(range) + COLUMNS(range)
)

GETTABLEOFCELL(tableCell)
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    ISCELLINRANGE(DeathWaveUW, tableCell), {DeathWaveUW},
    ISCELLINRANGE(BlackHoleUW, tableCell), {BlackHoleUW},
    // ...
  )
)

///

=ISCELLINRANGE(DeathWaveUW, D6) // => TRUE
=COLUMN(GETTABLEOFCELL(D6)) // => #VALUE!

=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    ISCELLINRANGE(DeathWaveUW, D6), DeathWaveUW
  )
) // => #N/A
```

As seen above, to debug `GETTABLEOFCELL()`, I simply copied a snippet of the formula into a cell with hard-coded values.  It returns `#N/A` saying there is no match in the `IFS()` list, which I am guessing (read: hoping) is the root issue in `GETTABLEOFCELL()`.  I've used both `DeathWaveUW` and `{DeathWaveUW}` syntaxes for the second argument of `IFS`; both return `#N/A`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Click on the `N/A`. It'll show a error. Quote the error. Is it `N/A` or `#VALUE`? Related/Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093325/mismatch-range-error-on-using-ifs-in-sheets/74094313#74094313

Comment: The first thing I would try is to remove the { curly braces } around those named range references in the function definition — they serve no purpose there. The `ifs()` function is quite picky when it comes to alternative results of differing dimensions, so you could try with nested `if()` functions instead. Finally, not all functions return references. Most return values. I do not know whether you can get a range reference from `ifs()` or `if()`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

`IFS` returns

- `#N/A`, when none of the conditions is satisfied
- `#VALUE`, when there are mismatched ranges

#### Solution:

For

- `#N/A`, Add a default value to `IFS`
- `#VALUE`, Fix the range size

#### Sample:

- `#N/A`

Add a default value:

```
GETTABLEOFCELL(tableCell)
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFS(
    ISCELLINRANGE(DeathWaveUW, tableCell), {DeathWaveUW},
    ISCELLINRANGE(BlackHoleUW, tableCell), {BlackHoleUW},
    TRUE, "No range found"
  )
)
```

This assumes All `*UW`s are of single range. If not, `TRUE` and `"No range found"` should be  modified to a array(`MAKEARRAY` is a option).

- `#VALUE`

If `DeathWaveUW` and `BlackHoleUW` and all other `UW`s were two dimensional and of the same size, you can change the aggregating function `AND` to a non-aggregating function like `*` to maintain the array size:

```
ISCELLINRANGE(range, cell)
=
  (ROW(cell) >= ROW(range))*
  (ROW(cell) < ROW(range) + ROWS(range))*
  (COLUMN(cell) >= COLUMN(range))*
  (COLUMN(cell) < COLUMN(range) + COLUMNS(range))
```

Alternatively, reduce the array size of named range to 1 by passing it as a string and use `INDIRECT`

```
GETTABLEOFCELL(tableCell)
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 INDIRECT(
  IFS(
    ISCELLINRANGE(DeathWaveUW, tableCell), "DeathWaveUW",
    ISCELLINRANGE(BlackHoleUW, tableCell), "BlackHoleUW",
    TRUE, "No range found"
  )
 )
)
```

##### Related:

- [ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets)
- [Mismatch Range error on using IFs in sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093325/mismatch-range-error-on-using-ifs-in-sheets/74094313#74094313)